# How to pass parameters to window in TinyMCE4?

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

TinyMCE4 is out of beta and the "documentation" for this particular need is here:

[http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4:method.tinymce.WindowManager.setParams](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4%3amethod.tinymce.WindowManager.setParams)

It's far from helpful. How do I use the `editor.windowManager.setParams()` method to populate values in a form in a plugin window? There is a note in the code which confirms then intention of the method, but none of the provided plugins use this method.

Comment: I ended up grabbing the form values in the dialog with jQuery in plugin.js. Not very happy with that but it does work. Someone feel free to tell me a cleaner solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting the answer that worked for me:

I ended up grabbing the form values in the dialog with jQuery in plugin.js. Not very happy with that but it does work. Someone feel free to tell me a cleaner solution!